# Determine the unique vector x in the row space for A, for which Ax = b.

Tags: matrices

So I have matrix
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&0&1\\
-1&-1&-1&0\\
1&0&2&-1\end{bmatrix}\qquad b=\begin{bmatrix}9\\-6\\3\end{bmatrix}$$
and I'm supposed to find the unique vector $x$ that lies in the row space of $A$, for which $Ax=b$.

From the equation $Ax=b$ I've come to the solution:

x_1=-2s+t-3   x_2=s-t+3  x_3=s  x_4=t

So:

[x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4]^T = s[-2 1 1 0]^T + t[1 -1 0 1]^T + [3 3 0 0]^T

And the row space for A is:

R(A) = span{(1 0 2 -1)^T, (0 1 -1 1)^T}

I saw some examples where the unique solution for x is the "shortest" solution, but I'm a little bit confused about that and in this case there are two free variables. I'm not quite sure how to proceed.

(So sorry for not being able to write in LaTeX, I'm a newbie :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x$ be the unique solution. Since you need a $x$ which is in row space of $A$.
$$\
x = A^Tw \quad \text{for some } w \in R^{3\times1}
$$
Substituting in the equation we get,
$$\
AA^Tw =b \\
w=(AA^T)^{-1}b \\
\implies x=A^T(AA^T)^{-1}b
$$
$AA^T$ is invertible if rows of $A$ are linearly independent. In your case rows of $A$ are not linearly independent and Hence, you do not get an unique $w$. But, the $x$ which you get is indeed unique. That is for any of the infinitely possible $w$s, you will get same $x$.

**Background:**
$Ax=b$ can have three outcomes Unique Solution, Infinitely many solutions, and No solution.

- Unique Solution: We get this if $A$ is invertible.
- Infinitely Many Solution: $A$ is not invertible and Null Space of $A$ is not empty. Precisely, If you give me a solution $x^*$. I can give you another solution $x$ by $x = x^*+y$ where $y \in N(A)$. This is a valid solution as $Ax = Ax^* + Ay=Ax^*+\pmb0$. In such a scenario we find a solution that is closest to the origin. It can be proved this special solution belongs to the row space of $A$. Proving this is not tough you can try it as an exercise.
- No Solution: In this case we try to find a solution that gives $b^*$ nearest to $b$. $Ax=b^*$ This is our standard Least Squared problem.

Comment: @JohnDoe I hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

To be in the row space means it is a linear combination of the rows seen as vectors. You can then solve these three simultaneous equations simultaneously by adding and subtracting them so reach the $(x,y,z)$ solution. A trick is to put the matrix into ‘row reduced echelon form’ (RREF; https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form). This allows us to simply open up the equations one at a time from the bottom row and substitute in the upper rows to very quickly find the solution.

Note however that the solution to $Ax=b$ is unique if and only if $A$ has linearly independent rows, which happens if and only if $A$ is invertible, so the unique solution is best found by computing $$x=A^{-1}\left(Ax\right)= A^{-1}b.$$

Stay safe